# pg_dump using connection string failed

Tags: postgresql, windows, pg-dump

On my mac OS machine, in bash, `pg_dump` using connection string is working correctly.

`pg_dump postgresql://<db_username>:<db_password>@<host>:5432/<db_name> --file=/Users/dump1234.tar --encoding=utf8 --format=t`

where `<db_password>` ends with '@' character and has few special characters.

However, on my Windows 10 machine, in bash, giving an error with the same connection string.

Comment: The `@` inside the password might be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is documented at [Connection Strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING).

The `@` character needs to be replaced in the password by `%40`.

Also bash will interpret an unquoted `#` as the start of a comment and an unquoted `!` as an event designator. The simplest way to avoid these interpretations is to put the whole URI inside single quotes:

```
pg_dump 'postgresql://thilllon:l2k2lllk2j3!%40!#$%40!!!%40@myproject.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/project1'
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. By the way, do you have any idea why was it working on my mac? actually sharp('#') was not in the password but exclamation mark('!') was.

Comment: @thilllon: maybe the default shell on Mac is not bash? But for the '@' inside the password, it conflicts with '@' as a separator with the host so I would expect this to fail on any platform.